# Need a help in ADO Board

Tags: azure-devops

We recently started using Microsoft ADO Board for out User stories and development activities. Plan is to introduce pipeline in later stage. but currently, this is process, when we have "New" user story, which will be picked up by "Developer" and peer reviewed by Sr. Developer and move to SIT team from client end. how to calculate my development time here. i want only the time taken by my development team to calculated. is there any out of box field to capture the time details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time tracking in Visual Studio Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379350/time-tracking-in-visual-studio-online)

Comment: Tracking can be done using fields like Remaining Work / Completed work.  If you want to break down multiple developers on a single task to get an aggregate or if you want to track time spent per develop per day, you probably need to leverage one of the extensions instead.  The answer on the linked item I think covers the basic case of just using the built-in tasks for development tracking.

Answer (score 0):

From the Marketplace, you can find few extensions to track time:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=time&target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Boards&visibilityQuery=all&sortBy=Relevance

You can select and install a suitable one from them to your Azure DevOps Organization. Then you can use the installed extension to record the time for your teams.